# Count Product was sold In MDX query

Tags: mdx

My MDX query as

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[SaleAMT]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]
    : 
      [Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-05-05T00:00:00] ON ROWS
FROM [Sale_Period_report];
```

I want to return a Count of product was sold, like that:

```
Date         SaleAmt    ProductSold
2015-04-01   20.000     150
2015-04-02   36.212     650
2015-04-05   10.333     65
```

Comment: Do you have a measure which provide the count of products sold? Should we assume ProductSold is a measure?

Comment: Do you have a measure `ProductSold` in your cube? What sort of Product dimension do you have in the cube? Currently it is not possible for us to help as you need to give complete information in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Against `AdvWrks`this combination of `COUNT` , `EXISTING` and a cross join seems to give me a variable result - what this result actually means I'm a little unsure:

```
WITH  
  MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS 
    Count
    (
      (EXISTING 
          [Product].[Product Categories].[Product]
        * 
          [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Count]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070701]
  : 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070731] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

So adapted to your cube it might look like:

```
WITH  
  MEMBER [Measures].[ProductsSold] AS 
    Count
    (
      (EXISTING 
          Products.Product.members
        * 
          [Measures].[SaleAMT])
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[SaleAMT]
   ,[Measures].[ProductsSold]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-05-05T00:00:00]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Sale_Period_report];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a measure which gives the products sold, use this query:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[SaleAMT], [Measures].[ProductsSold]}  ON COLUMNS,

    NON EMPTY {[Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]:
               [Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-05-05T00:00:00]
              } ON ROWS
    FROM [Sale_Period_report]
```

If you don't have such a measure, I will assume you would have a products Hierarchy in your cube like `Products.Product`.

In that case you have to create a calculated member which will give you the count.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ProductsSold] AS
COUNT(
        EXISTS(Products.Product.CHILDREN, 
        {[Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]:[Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-05-05T00:00:00]},
        "Sales"       
     )
```

And then it is the same:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[SaleAMT], [Measures].[ProductsSold]}  ON COLUMNS,

    NON EMPTY {[Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]:
               [Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-05-05T00:00:00]
              } ON ROWS
    FROM [Sale_Period_report]
```

I have assumed you have a measure group called `Sales`.

For a better answer you would have to give further details.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your query return a same result for all rows. I use this query: WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ProductsSold] AS
COUNT(
        EXISTS(Products.Product.CHILDREN, 
        {[Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]:[Account Date13h].[Date].&[2015-05-05T00:00:00]},
        "Sales"       
     )

Comment: (upped) I'd be more tempted to use `existing` rather than `exists`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ProductsSold] AS
    COUNT(NonEmpty([AccSetting].[AccID].[AccID].ALLMEMBERS, [Measures].[SaleAMT]))
```

I use this query and the OLAP return correctly what I want